# Make your own .sty files

Tags: package-writing

Sorry to start a subjective question, but want to understand "own.sty" file.

Other than all `\usepackage{}` what sort of other commands can be added to the makeyourown.sty file. 
Can you include `\let` command, and `\newcommands` in it.

What sort of precaution / structure newbies should follow.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the retag. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I tagged this with {documentclass}...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is a skeleton for an own package:

```
% this is my first package
% 
% (c) Buffalo Bill
%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN archives
%% in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
  [2011/01/11 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]

\RequirePackage{whateverwe need}
\newcommand{\hi}{Hello, this is my own package}
\let\myDate\date
\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{{#1Good Bye}}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mypackage.sty'.
```

You can put `mypackage.sty` in the same directory as the `.tex` file, into `~/texmf`, or somewhere else in latex's package search path—see `$ less "$(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)"`

Comment: And use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`.

Comment: @Juan- I am just curious to know why you asked me to use      \RequirePackage instead of \usepackage. Whats the difference. Sorry for coming back to the post this late.

Comment: The difference is that usepackage doesn't work and LaTeX provides the command RequirePackage, which loads all the required packages when the newly written style file is loaded in a document.

Comment: @gns-ank: why should `\usepackage` not work?

Comment: Maybe it does, I have not tried it, I just used RequirePackage always as it was suggested in Leslie Lamport's book LaTeX. I can not remember the real reason now. I found another question on stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage

Comment: So this shows, that actually, this only a convention and there is very little difference. Sorry for being sloppy previously.

Comment: (Commenting on this old thread for new people stumbling across it.) If your package imports something via `\usepackage` and the user then also tries to import the same thing, they will get an error. If you use `\RequirePackage` this will not happen.

Answer (score 17):

Package files are just input literally, so you can use any command that you can use in document files. Most often it makes sense to include a small amount of identification metadata, to support options, etc.; see clsguide.pdf (`texdoc clsguide`) for a good introduction.