# What's the difference between \RequirePackage and \usepackage?

Tags: macros, packages

I understand that ["the convention is to use `\RequirePackage` in a package or
class and `\usepackage` in a document"](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg77845.html), but apart from that, is there any practical difference between the two commands?

(I am thinking for example that it could be the case that `\RequirePackage` is a "stronger" command and you wouldn't run into problems with hyperref not being at the end)

Comment: You're question has been answered for the most part, so this is just a comment. What hasn't been answered was the final question about problems caused by hyperref not being at the end. RequirePackage isn't going to help with that problem. In fact, it may well make it worse. (What if you want to use two packages, both of which `RequirePackage{hyperref}` ?) Take great care if you `RequirePackage{hyperref}` in some package. It had better be the last package you need.

Comment: Well, yeah, I meant your, not you are. Yet another example of the necessity of editors.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Sorry but there is a difference, you can write :

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}      
\documentclass ....
```

and not

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}      
\documentclass ...
```

Comment: I created `myclass.cls`, and `\documentclass{myclass}` it on `main.tex`. As per comment and answers around here I cannot `usepackage{anypackage}` before `\documentclass{myclass}` on `main.tex`. But looks like I still can `usepackage{anypackage}` on `myclass.cls`, which I wasn't expecting. Does this makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean? The two code snippets are exactly the same with the only difference being whether `RequirePackage` or `usepackage` is used.

Comment: The point here is that the first snippet is valid but the second snippet is not since `\usepackage{...}` cannot be used before `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 148):

The only difference is that `\usepackage` cannot be used before `\documentclass`. Otherwise there is no functional difference. The LaTeX kernel defines `\usepackage` to issue an error message initially, and `\documentclass` is defined as

```
\def\documentclass{%
  \let\documentclass\@twoclasseserror % a second \documentclass command produces an error
  \if@compatibility\else\let\usepackage\RequirePackage\fi % define \usepackage to be the same as \RequirePackage
  \@fileswithoptions\@clsextension}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer added a lot to my understanding, but I will accept @Altermundus' answer since it was given first.

Comment: @Vivi Not the best reason to accept an answer, but the choice is yours. :)

Comment: @vivi: A very bad reason indeed.

Answer (score 45):

From a technical point `\usepackage` is first defined to the error message `\usepackage before \documentclass` but than set to the definition of `\RequirePackage` by the `\documentclass` before the class file is loaded.
You can use `\RequirePackage` before `\documentclass`, which might be sometimes required.

However, the true difference is the logical usage: `\usepackage` is an user macro intended for the document file while `\RequirePackage` is intended for package and class files to describe dependencies. Using `\usepackage` inside a package will also work, as long it isn't loaded with `\RequirePackage` before `\documentclass`. :-)

Comment: I don't really get the point of this "logical usage". If a package *uses* another package, then it surely requires it! From the naming of the macros I was always under the impression that \RequirePackage was taking extra care in order to warrant the package to being loaded without "loading" it twice in case it was already loaded by someone else. But it seems I was wrong. I guess package designers don't want to impose the requirement of even having a \documentclass statement. Therefore, they use \RequirePackage.

Comment: Well, to me it sounds like "This package has this dependency, but if the dependency is already loaded (by some other package or explicitly by the user with `\usepackage`), do nothing.".

Answer (score 17):

you can use `\RequirePackage` *before* the `\documentclass` statement, which has some advantages in some special cases.

Comment: As I understood reading up to now, \usepackage was intentionally created in order to avoid people "using packages" before the \documentclass statement. Therefore, I guess emphasis should be given on why is it a problem if you put thing before documentclass, and when and why it is unavoidable or not worth avoiding.

Answer (score 1):

Both expand to `\@fileswithoptions \@pkgextension`. I.e., no difference.

Comment: no, that's not correct ...

Comment: `\usepackage` is first defined to an error message but than `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage` is executed by `\documentclass`.

Comment: @Herbert: Sure. I can think of exactly one situation where one needs to include a package before a documentclass. Maybe there are others, but for most purposes, they are functionally identical and certainly one is not "stronger" than another.

Comment: @TH what is that situation?

Comment: @rogerl It has been years, but I'm pretty sure I was thinking of the `fix-cm` package that should be loaded via `\RequirePackage` before the `\documentclass`: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf But https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360656/tikz-spy-and-background-libraries-with-etex-and-pgfplots-packages-in-beamer makes a good case for a second.