# What causes this strange interaction between glossaries and amsmath?

Tags: amsmath, glossaries, incompatibility, mathspec

MWE: greatly trimmed from a large document; XeLaTeX; full TeXLive2012 completely up-to-date:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Fails with "! Package mathspec Error: 'amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'."

Now, if I eliminate `glossaries`, or move it above mathspec in the file, things work. But it isn't very convenient to have to sort ones packages whenever anything gets a new dependency. And in any case, I *do* load amsmath before mathspec, don't I?

Really puzzled by this one. Any illumination would be most welcome.

(BTW, not *strictly* MWE, as it also fails with `article`.

Comment: `glossaries` (in particular `datatool-base`) requires `amsmath`. The check performed by `mathspec` consists in redefining `\RequirePackage` to check whether the argument is `amsmath` (which is a very poor trick, IMO).

Comment: @egreg: If you'd like to turn a brilliant comment into a brilliant answer (as usual!), I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that one of the subpackages loaded by `datatool`, namely `datatool-base` has the line

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
```

and `mathspec` sets up a (very poor) check for possible loading of `amsmath` after it, which triggers the error even if `amsmath` has *already* been loaded when another package requires it.

The normal setup of LaTeX is not reloading packages, so the call by `datatool-base` should be completely harmless, as far as `mathspec` is concerned. This is undoubtedly a bug.

---

The package `mathspec` says

```
\let\original@RequirePackage\RequirePackage
\renewcommand\RequirePackage[2][]{
  \ifstrequal{#2}{amsmath}
    {\PackageError{mathspec}
       {`amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'}
       {Edit the document so that `amsmath' is required earlier than `mathspec'.}}
    {\relax}
  \original@RequirePackage[#1]{#2}}
\@onlypreamble\RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\@onlypreamble\usepackage
```

which is quite bad code, in my opinion: `\RequirePackage` is redefined to check if its mandatory argument is *exactly* `amsmath`. So, if one says

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
```

the check will fail and `amsmath` will be happily loaded after `mathspec`.

Judging from the comments in the package, the *only* reason why `amsmath` should be loaded before `mathspec` is a problem with the definition of `\varTheta`. This can be solved much more easily by changing lines 103–106, which read

```
103 \ifdef{\varTheta}
104   {\let\eu@cm@varTheta\varTheta}
105   {\relax}
106 \let\varTheta\Theta
```

into

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \ifdef{\varTheta}
    {\let\eu@cm@varTheta\varTheta}
    {}
\let\varTheta\Theta
}
```

and removing the final lines with the redefinition of `\RequirePackage`.

---

A workaround until the `mathspec` package is fixed:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\makeatletter % undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. @egreg, perfect as usual. It fixes my problem, and I've forwarded it, with a reference to here, to the Maintainer.

Comment: Does this only work when used in the preamble? I tried to use it within a cls file (commenting out the `\let\usepackage\RequrePackage` line) but it seemed to only produce (a tonne of) errors. I finally was able to figure out a workaround such that I could include it properly within the preamble, by using this *before* I `\usepackage{mathtools}`, but leaving the other stuff in the class file. To clarify…mathspec needed to be loaded in the cls, and it caused no problems, but when mathtools was used in the preamble all hell broke loose.

Comment: @mpacer This is too vague, I think. You should remove `\makeatletter and `\makeatother`, as far as I can see. The `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage` line is important.

Comment: @egreg, tried that too, thought they looked out of place in a class file. But unfortunately, no dice. You shouldn't be able to use `\usepackage` before the declaration of a document class with (for example)  `\documentclass{book}` in the .tex file itself, no?

Comment: Hmmm maybe what I should have done is add the `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage` in the .tex preamble, but not in the class file itself.

Comment: For reference (not for @egreg but others who may end up here) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage discusses what I was referring to above regarding the difference between `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage`

Comment: This is still an issue. :S