# Glossaries and corner cases

Tags: glossaries

In general the glossaries interface seems straightforward with it's default settings for acronyms, however, I came across some cornercases, where I would like to change the way glossaries displays a specific term differently.

Examples would be the following:

The acronym `FUSE`, while in general I like the default representation of the form My Long Acronym (MLA), it feels unnatural for `Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)`. I would more likely write `... implemented with FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) ...` than the other way round.

Another example for a corner case would be `PCIe` which stands for `Peripheral Component Interconnect Express`, which however I would only like to see as `PCI Express (PCIe)` in the first use place, but in the glossary I would like to see the longer description of `Peripheral Component Interconnect Express`.

### Question

1. How can I achieve a different order (`\glsname (\glsdesc)`) for *specific* entries of a glossary (the acronym glossary)? (Preferably without retyping the data in `name` and `description`, Would it be possible to define a macro, that calculates first correctly?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a mixture of styles like this, I think it's better to use [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) rather than just `glossaries`. This extension to the `glossaries` package reimplements abbreviations to make it easier to have multiple styles.

Instead of using `\setacronymstyle{style-name}`, you need to use `\setabbreviationstyle[category]{style-name}` where the optional argument is a category label. (If omitted, `abbreviation` is used.) So if the majority of your abbreviations should have a long (short) style, then you'd use

```
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
```

(before defining the abbreviations). This is actually the default.

For your short (long) abbreviations, you just need to decide on an appropriate category label (let's say `reverse`) and set the style for that category:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[reverse]{short-long}
```

The abbreviations are defined using `\newabbreviation`, which has a similar syntax to `\newacronym` from `glossaries` but the optional argument has an extra key `category` which is set to `abbreviation` by default. (This key is also available in `\newglossaryentry` with `glossaries-extra`, but defaults to `general` in that case.)

So for your first two examples:

```
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\setabbreviationstyle[reverse]{short-long}

\newabbreviation{mla}{MLA}{my long abbreviation}
\newabbreviation[category=reverse]{fuse}{FUSE}{Filesystem in Userspace}
```

There's a predefined category label called `acronym` and `glossaries-extra` redefines

```
\newacronym[options]{label}{short}{long}
```

to

```
\newabbreviation[category=acronym,options]{label}{short}{long}
```

The style for the `acronym` category is automatically set to just `short`, but you can set it explicitly. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\newacronym[description={device that produces an intense narrow
beam of light}]
 {laser}% label
 {laser}% short
 {light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation}% long
```

This style won't actually show the long form unless the entry is used with commands like `\glsxtrlong` or `\glsentrylong`. However, with `glossaries-extra` you can adjust the post description hook for a particular category. For example:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
 \space(\textsc{acronym:} \glsentrylong{\glscurrententrylabel})%
}
```

This saves creating a custom glossary style. (Note that in this case `\glsxtrpostdescacronym` needs redefining, but for a custom category, such as the `reverse` one above, the hook won't be predefined.)

Another variation is to set attributes for a particular category to adjust the style. For example, you can make `\newabbreviation` automatically insert dots between each letter of the short form by setting the `insertdots` attribute for a particular category. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[dottedsc]{short-sc-long}
\glssetcategoryattribute{dottedsc}{insertdots}{true}
```

If you set the `insertdots` attribute, it's a good idea to also set the `discardperiod` attribute which will discard a period immediately following commands like `\gls` to prevent a double-dot.

You can also define a "tagging" command for a particular category (or categories):

```
\GlsXtrEnableInitialTagging{dottedsc}{\itag}
```

The first argument may be a comma-separated list of category labels rather than just a single label. The second argument is a command name of your choosing that you can use to tag the initial letters. (This should not be an existing command.) For example:

```
\newabbreviation
 [category=dottedsc]
 {html}% identifying label
 {html}% short form
 {\itag{h}yper\itag{t}ext \itag{m}arkup \itag{l}anguage}% long form

\newabbreviation
 [category=dottedsc]
 {xml}% identifying label
 {xml}% short form
 {e\itag{x}tensible \itag{m}arkup \itag{l}anguage}% long form
```

In the glossary, the tagged letters will by default be underlined but not in the rest of the document.

I've left your third example until last as it's a tricky one. Even though you don't want to use the `description` key, I think it's necessary in this case. Either:

```
\newabbreviation
 [description={Peripheral Component Interconnect Express}]
 {pcie}{PCIe}{PCI Express}
```

or, if you also want `pci` indexed:

```
\newabbreviation{pci}{PCI}{Peripheral Component Interconnect}

\newabbreviation[description={\glsxtrlong{pci} Express}]{pcie}{PCIe}{PCI Express}
```

or, if you don't want `pci` indexed:

```
\newabbreviation{pci}{PCI}{Peripheral Component Interconnect}

\newabbreviation[description={\glsentrylong{pci} Express}]{pcie}{PCIe}{PCI Express}
```

Nested use of commands like `\gls` within the long (or short) form can cause all kinds of problems, although `glossaries-extra` tries to eliminate some of them. This is discussed in more detail in the section ["Nested Links"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested) of the `glossaries-extra` manual.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
 [
   %abbreviations, % for separate list of abbreviations
   %nopostdot=false % auto-insert full-stop after descriptions
 ]
 {glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

% Regular entry (category automatically set to "general")
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

% Standard long (short) abbreviations
% This is already the default, but set it explicitly for this
% example.
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

% Category automatically set to "abbreviation" if not explicitly set
\newabbreviation{mla}{MLA}{my long abbreviation}

\newabbreviation
 [description={Peripheral Component Interconnect Express}]
 {pcie}{PCIe}{PCI Express}

% Reverse short (long) abbreviations.
% Let's call this category "reverse". This is just a label you can change
% but make sure it doesn't contain special characters.

\setabbreviationstyle[reverse]{short-long}

\newabbreviation[category=reverse]{fuse}{FUSE}{Filesystem in Userspace}

% There's already a predefined category called "acronym" that
% has the abbreviation style set to "short", but let's set it explicitly 
% in this example.

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\newacronym[description={device that produces an intense narrow
beam of light}]
 {laser}% label
 {laser}% short
 {light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation}% long

% The "short" style won't show the long form in the glossary,
% so let's adjust the post description hook just for the "acronym"
% category so that the long form is automatically inserted after the
% description. This saves defining a new custom glossary style.

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
 \space(\textsc{acronym:} \glsentrylong{\glscurrententrylabel})%
}

% Let's make a dotted small-caps category called "dottedsc":
\setabbreviationstyle[dottedsc]{long-short-sc}

% provide a tagging command for the "dottedsc" category:
\GlsXtrEnableInitialTagging{dottedsc}{\itag}

% auto insert dots between letters in the short form for the
% "dottedsc" category:
\glssetcategoryattribute{dottedsc}{insertdots}{true}

% Discard trailing periods following commands like \gls:
\glssetcategoryattribute{dottedsc}{discardperiod}{true}

\newabbreviation
 [category=dottedsc]
 {html}% identifying label
 {html}% short form
 {\itag{h}yper\itag{t}ext \itag{m}arkup \itag{l}anguage}% long form

\newabbreviation
 [category=dottedsc]
 {xml}% identifying label
 {xml}% short form
 {e\itag{x}tensible \itag{m}arkup \itag{l}anguage}% long form


\begin{document}

\section{First}
First use:

\gls{sample}.

\gls{mla}.

\gls{fuse}.

\gls{laser}.

\gls{html}.

\gls{xml}.

\gls{pcie}.

\section{Next}

Next use:

\gls{sample}.

\gls{mla}.

\gls{fuse}.

\gls{laser}.

\gls{html}.

\gls{xml}.

\gls{pcie}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Answer (score 0):

In your FUSE example, if you can't redefine your first use for these terms in general because you are using `\arc{}` you may be able to define a new command to accomplish this when you know in advance you are using a term that requires this special treatment.

A starting point might be:
`\newcommand{\acrinverse}[1]{{\acrshort{#1}}\xspace{\acrlong{#1}}}`

I think you may find it easier to use `\gls{}` and `\newglossaryentry` commands rather than the faster `\acr{}` because you will be able define each

- label
- name
- sort
- short
- long
- description
- first

all manually to conform to entry specific formatting.

With regards to your formatting, I don't think any special macro would be needed to sort, you can just define the sorting term logic within the sort field.  This term will not be visible, so modify it as you need to.

Continuing your PCI example if you want to build a more dynamic solution, you could consider nesting your terms? I did something like this and I sought help in these two questions:

[Nested conditional glossary terms using Glossaries \ifglsused in \newglossaryentry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228904/nested-conditional-glossary-terms-using-glossaries-ifglsused-in-newglossaryent)

and

[Create new fields in glossaries newglossaryentry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231144/create-new-fields-in-glossaries-newglossaryentry)