# Access specific glossary fields without triggering first usage

Tags: macros, conditionals, glossaries, environment-variables

I would like to know if any of the fields that are manually configured during the creation of glossary entries can be accessed manually/deliberately in a macro or newcommand - possibly of the form:

```
\newcommand{\expectedFirst}[1]{???}
```

where ??? would be a defintion that would use the gls label, #1, to grab a predefined field such as short, name, label, long, description, firstplural, etc.  I would create a new command for each field I wanted to pull, or possibly use

```
\newcommand{\expectedField}[2]{???}
```

where #1 would be the label string, 
and #2 represents the field I want to extract or make accessible.

I poked through the .dtx glossaries file but didn't find any macro definitions that looked like a variable creation that I could duplicate externally.  What did look interesting and potentially useful was the presence of a tracking boolean to track whether the term had been called yet or not.  This boolean would be another variable I would be interested in comparing with in my custom macros.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


%=========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR GLOSSARIES
%=========================================================================================================================================

% Glossaries must be loaded before amsmath as per details in the following forum answer
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85696/what-causes-this-strange-interaction-between--and-amsmath
\usepackage[nogroupskip,toc,acronym]{glossaries} % must come after href   
\usepackage{scrwfile}%http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#glsnewwriteexceeded

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{ICPMS}{ type={acronym}, sort={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry},  name={ICPMS}, short={ICPMS}, long={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry}, first={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry (ICPMS)}, description={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry} }

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \gls{ICPMS}
        \item \gls{ICPMS}
            %\item \expectedFirst{ICPMS}
    \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you can certainly do it for *new* fields, right? Just as you can use `\glspl` to get the plural form, even if the plural is non-standard and specified via the entry field. See section 4.3 (currently start page 79) of the manual. `firstplural` etc. already have existing macros as described slightly earlier in the manual (around p. 74).

Comment: @cfr Thankyou for your comment, but I am not trying to create new types of entries.  I am trying to access entries without triggering formal use recognition to put together a system for evaluating the current state of a glossary entry by retrieving the text returned by a \gls{X} call and comparing it to a field in that same entry.  I don't think a custom key would work in this context.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was suggesting looking at how that is done. Well, for things like `firstplural` etc., the commands already exist. That is, they retrieve the content of a particular field or return a default defined in terms of the entry name.

Comment: @cfr sorry I misunderstood I will look back to the code with firstplural as the specific macro definition. I will update the question with my extracted attempt adapted from this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through more careful inspection of the documentation and from inspirations garnered from the comments in the original question, I have found that the `glossaries` package makes some fields accessible using commands formated similar to `\glsentryshort{}` and `\glsentrylong{}`.  Most importantly, using these commands doesn't artificially trigger a counter that would prevent the appropriate first use evaluation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%=========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR GLOSSARIES
%=========================================================================================================================================

% Glossaries must be loaded before amsmath as per details in the following forum answer
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85696/what-causes-this-strange-interaction-between--and-amsmath
\usepackage[nogroupskip,toc,acronym]{glossaries} % must come after href   
\usepackage{scrwfile}%http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#glsnewwriteexceeded

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{ICPMS}{ type={acronym}, sort={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry},  name={ICPMS}, short={ICPMS}, long={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry}, first={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry (ICPMS)}, description={inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry} }

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \glsentrylong{ICPMS}
        \item \glsentryshort{ICPMS}
        \item \glsentryfull{ICPMS}
        \item \gls{ICPMS}
        \item \gls{ICPMS}
    \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```