# Glossaries for multiple chapters in different files

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, multiple-files

I have a question regarding putting glossaries / acronyms in my appendix pages. I followed this post as an example and everything went fine:

[How can i get the abbreviations as list in Appendix page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42966/how-can-i-get-the-abbreviations-as-list-in-appendix-page)

However I have trouble using it in this template for my report:

https://github.com/edwardtoday/MSc_dissertation/blob/master/ref_templates/ociamthesis/ociamthesismain.tex

It's because in this template I have different chapters, which are written in different .tex file and combined together later in main.tex. Therefore the [glossaries] package seems to be confused and it can't perform cross reference to the acronyms and glossaries I have in each chapters... 
It doesn't work at all...
Do you have any idea how I can make glossaries for multiple chapters in different files?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: There's certainly no general problem doing this. You just do it the way you would do it anyway and it all works fine. So there must be something else about your document which is causing the issue. Try to create a minimal example document you can post here which people can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a similar problem to that described by the original poster in this question:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234105/problems-with-printglossaries-in-main-tex-using-external-glossary-file-and-exter/234262#234262  sounds like you just want to move your `\printglossaries` command into the appendices environment.  Similar to the structured examples in the answers, if you can update your question to include a MWE structured like your document, I will help troubleshoot.