# Code is a mess because I cannot indent inside a for loop in my algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

I have a for loop in my algorithm and I can't get latex to properly indent the pseudocode inside it. It's just a mess at the moment, it won't even put the code in the for loop on separate lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf]{caption}
\RequirePackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Generate transition matrix for one-dimensional quantum walk}\label{tran_mat_1d_qw}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{generateTransitionMatrix}{$steps$}
    \State $numElements \gets steps * 4 + 2$
    \State $transitionMat \gets numElements \times numElements$ MATRIX

    \BlankLine
    \State $col \gets 0$
    \For {$i = 1 \to (steps * 2) - 1$}
        \State row \gets i * 2$
        \STATE\hspace{\algorithmicindent} transitionMat[row,      col]        \gets $1$
        \STATE\hspace{\algorithmicindent} transitionMat[row,      col + 1]    \gets $1$
        \STATE\hspace{\algorithmicindent} transitionMat[row + 5,  col]        \gets $1$
        \STATE\hspace{\algorithmicindent} transitionMat[row + 5,   col + 1]   \gets $-1$
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is helpful if your MWE starts with `\documentclass` and includes all your packages and definitions so that it can be compiled readily by those trying to help you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have edited in the package being used.

Comment: That's better, but it still does not compile (`\begin{document}` must follow the `\usepackage` declarations).  Also, since the document class is not standard, the rest of us can't access it.  Are you able to recreate the problem using a standard document class like `article`?  If so, that makes for a much more useful MWE.  Additionally, things like `\BlankLine` are not defined by the standard document classes.  While I can guess what it might mean, it makes for a lot of work for those trying to help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am using the online tool ShareLatex to build my document. I wasn't aware that \begin{document} must follow the \usepackage declarations, I will take note of that for future question. I just tried using article as my document class and the document failed to compile :(

Comment: Well, I am not able to help, but I did find a listing for this class at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unaguil/thesis-latex/master/Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls, if that might help others...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how `\BlankLines` is defined, so I've removed that. If you want an unnumbered, empty line use `\Statex`.

There are numerous problems with your code.

- `\gets` must be placed in math mode, i.e. it needs to be within a pair of dollar signs. When outside math mode it generates the `missing $ inserted` error.
- In the first `\State` in the for loop you have forgotten the opening `$`, there is just the one at the end of the line.
- *Macros are case sensitive*, this means that `\State` is *not* the same as `\STATE`. The `algorithmicx` package defines the former, so change all `\STATE` to `\State`. Similarly, `\ENDFOR` should be `\EndFor` (read the documentation for `algorithmicx`/`algpseudocode`).

  These mistakes generate `Undefined control sequence` errors.
- You have to close the `\Procedure` with an `\EndProcedure`. This generates an error from `algorithmicx` saying `Some blocks are not closed!!!`.

Other comments:

- When writing words (as opposed to variables, such as `x`), use either `\text{the word(s)}` or `\mathrm{the word(s)}`, which typesets them in a roman font.
- You use `\times` one place, and `*` other places, use `\times` consistently.
- Concerning your preamble: You load `caption` twice, with different arguments, why? Add all the arguments to a single call of `caption`. You also load both `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` twice, which is pointless.

  Finally, the convention is to use `\usepackage` and not `\RequirePackage` in preambles, though they do the same thing. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19933/586

---

In the code below I removed the unused packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Generate transition matrix for one-dimensional quantum walk}\label{tran_mat_1d_qw}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{generateTransitionMatrix}{$\mathrm{steps}$}
    \State $\mathrm{numElements} \gets \mathrm{steps} \times 4 + 2$
    \State $\mathrm{transitionMat} \gets \mathrm{numElements} \times \mathrm{numElements}$ MATRIX
    \State $\mathrm{col} \gets 0$
    \For {$i = 1 \to (\mathrm{steps} \times 2) - 1$}
        \State $\mathrm{row} \gets i \times 2$
        \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $\mathrm{transitionMat[row,      col]       } \gets 1$
        \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $\mathrm{transitionMat[row,      col + 1]}    \gets 1$
        \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $\mathrm{transitionMat[row + 5,  col]       } \gets 1$
        \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $\mathrm{transitionMat[row + 5,   col + 1]}   \gets -1$
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```