# Weird asterisk in ToC and section* not working when using siunitx

Tags: table-of-contents, siunitx

I have a weird problem with `siunitx` and redefining section. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

As you can see, an asterisk appears in the ToC, aswell as the \section* command not working properly. The heading will be a star, and the actual heading goes into the text. It seems like the \section* command interprets the asterisk as the heading, and ignores the rest. So the asterisk in the ToC is more of a symptom...

Here is a MWE (rather MNWE):

> main.tex

```
\documentclass{styles/diplclass1} 
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section*{Starheading}
asdf

\section{Normal heading}
\end{document}
```

> styles/diplclass1.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{styles/diplclass1}
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}%
  {1}
  {0mm}
  {2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}
  {0.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}
  {\Large\bfseries}
}
```

Please note: I need to redefine sections, because I apply some styles there. Also, I need to use `siunitx`. I have not found anything when searching for this problem, except some issues with bibliography which seem to be related, as well as the fact, that redefining `\section` is okay for `\section*`, because `\@startsection` takes care of the asterisk version.

As soon as I remove the `siunitx` import, or the section redefinition, it works as expected. How can I redefine the section style, and use `siunitx` aswell? Does anyone have an idea why this problem occurs?

Comment: have you tried `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`? (Cf. [What's the difference between \RequirePackage and \usepackage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage))

Comment: I just did, it does not seem change anything. But thanks for the heads up

Comment: @ebo the two commands are `\let` equal to each other so it is not going to make any difference there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep, I've seen it after Ulrike's answer... but didn't deleted my comment since Christian answered it. Anyway, my hint didn't helped at all indeed. `:-s`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `\@startsection` in the KOMA-classes, the definition of the sectioning commands in KOMA are different. Use the tools offered by the class:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex,
  afterskip=0.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex,
  font=\Large\bfseries]{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section*{Starheading}
asdf

\section{Normal heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addition:

Normally KOMA would warn you when you do such a redefinition and fallback to another redefition. But through siunitx you are loading the amsgen package which redefines `\@ifstar` and now the test of KOMA fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about that. But when I replace my previous renewcommand with the KOMA RedeclareSectionCommand, I get the error: Undefined control sequence: \RedeclareSectonCommand. I guess it means, that my srcbook package is outdated, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChristianDreher: Yes.

Comment: After updating koma-script it worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your qualified help :))