# Latex won class and macros

Tags: macros, templates, document-classes

I'm writing my own simple template, what I have so far is a new, redefined make title command:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2016/06/22 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newcommand{\LOGO}{logo.png}
\newcommand{\FIRST}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SECOND}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\THIRD}[1]{#1}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace{10pt}
        \hbox{
            \mbox{
                \hspace{-20pt}
                \fbox{ \includegraphics{\LOGO}}
                \hspace{4pt}
            }
            \vrule depth 0.9\textheight
            \mbox{\hspace{2em}}
            \vtop{
                \vspace{20pt}
                \begin{flushleft}
                    \Large \FIRST \par
                \end{flushleft}
                \vspace{80pt}
                \begin{flushleft}
                    \Huge \bfseries \SECOND \par
                \end{flushleft}
                \begin{flushleft}
                    \large \bfseries \THIRD  \par
                \end{flushleft}
                \vfil
            }
        }
    \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
}
```

In the new `maketitle` I'm using macros `\FIRST, \SECOND, \THIRD` which I defined as :

```
\newcommand{\FIRST}[1]{#1}
```

However, I would like the user using this template to be able to upload during writing the tex while any value to `\FIRST` is such a way that when the user is calling my `\maketitle`, in place of `\FIRST` appears the value selected by the user. How can I do that, when I define `\FIRST` macro in the .cls file?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage

Comment: Please not that providing a template is a responsible task, since people rely on your work. In the code shown by you i can see several things that are bad. I suggest to read a bit more LaTeX stuff before going on. [Template Confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your commands like given below:

```
\newcommand{\FIRST}[1]{\gdef\@FIRST{#1}}
\newcommand{\SECOND}[1]{\gdef\@SECOND{#1}}
\newcommand{\THIRD}[1]{\gdef\@THIRD{#1}}
\let\@FIRST\@empty
\let\@SECOND\@empty
\let\@THIRD\@empty
```

Then later inside `\maketitle` you could replace `\FIRST`, `\SECOND` and `\THIRD` to `\@FIRST`, `\@SECOND` and `\@THIRD` respectively.

Now user can give:

```
\FIRST{one}
\SECOND{two}
\THIRD{three}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!