# Border around Image

Tags: floats, border

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm using a template created by another person and I'd like to make a modification. The template uses a subfunction to create figures and I'd like to add a border to all images.

I currently insert a figure like this:

```
\munepsfig[width=5in]{CG289}{CG289}
```

The `munepsfig` is a sub function created in a `.sty` file. The sub function looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\munepsfig}[3][scale=1.0]{%
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \vspace{2mm}
        \includegraphics[#1]{figures/#2.png}
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#2}
    \end{figure}
}
```

I've tried a number of suggestions from the internet but nothing seems to show up - the figure always shows with no change or the script fails. I'm just looking for a black border of a thickness I can choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a border for an image you can use the command `\framebox{}`. To define the width of the rule you can use command `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}`.

Both combined leads to the following

```
\newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{% <===============================
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \vspace{2mm}
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{#4} % <===================================
        \framebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2.png}} % <=====================
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#2}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Now you can use the command

```
%\munepsfig[option]{figure}{caption}{fboxrule}
\munepsfig[width=5cm]{example-image}{caption of figure}{1pt}
```

to print the image `example-image` with an border of `1pt`.

The complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{% <===============================
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \vspace{2mm}
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{#4} % <===================================
        \framebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2.png}} % <=====================
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#2}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

%\munepsfig[option]{figure}{caption}{fboxrule}
\munepsfig[width=5cm]{example-image}{caption of figure}{1pt}

\munepsfig[width=5cm]{example-image-a}{caption of figure2}{0.5pt}

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image: resulting images]

To get rid of the space between image and rule use command `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`.  See the following new MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{% <===============================
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \vspace{2mm}
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{#4} % <===================================
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} % <===================================
        \framebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2.png}} % <=====================
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#2}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

%\munepsfig[option]{figure}{caption}{fboxrule}
\munepsfig[width=5cm]{example-image}{caption of figure}{1pt}

\munepsfig[width=5cm]{example-image-a}{caption of figure2}{0.5pt}
\end{document}
```

resulting in the pdf:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there any way I get rid of the white space inside of the black border?

Answer (score 2):

With `pstricks` it is fairly easy to achieve this.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{%
     \begin{figure}[!htbp]
         \centering
         \vspace{2mm}
         \psframebox[linewidth=#4]{\includegraphics[#1]{figures/#2.eps}}
         \caption{#3}
         \label{fig:#2}
     \end{figure}
 }

 \begin{document}
 \munepsfig[scale=0.5]{MarmotOutlook}{Outlook.}{2pt}

 \end{document}
```

EDIT: Now the same thing with `TiKz`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{%
     \begin{figure}[!htbp]
         \centering
         \vspace{2mm}
         \tikz\node[draw=black,line width=#4](#2){\includegraphics[#1]{figures/#2.png}};
         \caption{#3}
         \label{fig:#2}
     \end{figure}
 }

 \begin{document}
 \munepsfig[scale=0.5]{MarmotOutlook}{Outlook.}{2pt}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to give this a shot, but my inexperience in latex is probably preventing me. I've placed the \usepackage{pstricks} command in both the main document just below \begin{document} and in the .sty file. I get an error pstricks.sty not found, so I'm guessing this wasn't included in my initial installation. I've found a version of it here:
http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/latex/pstricks.sty
and I place that with all the other files, but then it says pstricks.tex not found. Am I going down the wrong rabbit hole? Thanks!

Comment: @TrevorHarris : You cannot put a `\usepackage` command after `\begin{document}`. And of course you must have `pstricks` installed, but as far as I know it is part of any standard TeX installation, so I am surprised to hear about the error. Further, if you load a package in another package, you may [better use `RequirePackage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage).