# White border around figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am using LaTeX/Beamer to create some slides I have made the background black and the font white using

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black}
```

However, when I include an image using `\includegraphics` I see a little white shadow around the figure as in the following screenshot:

[image: white border]

I tried to use `trim=4 4 4 4, clip` in the options of `\includegraphics`, but it didn't help. I have checked the image and I don't see any white border around it; if there were one, it should be removed with `trim` and `clip`.

This is how to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[mathserif,xcolor={dvipsnames, svgnames},9.5pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} 

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamersize{text margin left = 1em}
\setbeamersize{text margin right = 1em}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{--}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=mycol}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=mycol}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\checkmark}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mycol}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg mycol}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=mycol}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, page=1]{hand2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

File `hand2` is a PDF that can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QWxMEsB_WjngTtGTobIo8sv38iBfnzgH/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: how about putting a black `fbox` around the figure -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400746/border-around-image

Comment: You left us to guessing. We haven't any information how you include your image in frame. So, please be so kind and provide small but complete document, which reproduce showed image.

Comment: @jsbibra I tried it, but the white border remains inside the box.

Comment: @Zarko good point - I updated my question.

Comment: I can't see a white boarder with mac perview.app https://i.stack.imgur.com/c663q.png . I suspect a viewer issue.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz you are looking at the original file. The white border shows up when I include the image in the my slides. See the first figure in my question.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis I'm looking at the compiled output. You can see the page number at the bottom right