# When or why should I use %% as opposed to %?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, comments

I've noticed that many (all?) style and class files have "documentation blocks" with a double comment character at the beginning of the line,

```
%% like so
```

instead of the usual style of comments,

```
% like so
```

Why is this done? Do some kinds of comments need the `%%` for some preprocessing/automatic documentation generation/etc. - or is it just customary? Should I mix `%%` and `%` in the same file for different uses?

(Specifically, an answer to [Make your own .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8752/5640) suggests single-comment-char comments, which added to my confusion.)

Comment: For a reference specifically to `.dtx` files, see the UK TeX FAQ entry on [Documented LaTeX sources (`.dtx` files)](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=dtx).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Many classes and packages are written using [`docstrip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) which strips all normal comments from the file and can combine or split material to different files. Comments with two percent characters are called *meta-characters* and are not stripped but written directly to the class or package file itself. Therefore you won't find full-line single-`%` comments in these files. Besides this there is no difference between both comments. 
See the [`docstrip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) and [`dtxtut`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut) manuals for more information.

Answer (score 34):

There's no built-in different behavior between `%%` and `%`; but as a consequence of how the `docstrip` works in extracting the code from a documented source `.dtx` file, usually the prolog and the final lines start with `%%`.

Of course one can use differently marked lines for preprocessing, but from a pure TeX point of view, those lines are perfectly equivalent.

I sometimes find it convenient to use multiple `%` character to mark particular spots of a document, as opposed to simple comments, to do searches more easily; for example, commands inserted in the final revision to adjust line or page breaks, or special reminders in general:

```
text where something special
%%% Inserted a page break, check the output!
\pagebreak
%%%
has been inserted to get a better page break
```

Thus it's possible to check all special things (which can be different from `\pagebreak` by searching for `%%%`. One can devise various marking schemes based on the fact that lines starting with `%` are ignored.

Comment: So there is no convention of where to use single or double `%` that compares to [the conventions of comments in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365334/lisp-commenting-convention)?

Comment: @N.N. There is in the `.dtx` format, but not in TeX proper. Also in PostScript `%%` is different from `%`.