# How can I get the Title, Author, and Date on the same line?

Tags: titles, titlesec, titling

I would like to have

- Title flush left
- Author flush right
- Date flush right

How can I do this on the same line or on a shared line? I was hope to achieve the following:

[image: Title Author Date shared line]

This is as far as I got using xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{Woche\hspace{.3cm}\thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}\begin{flushleft}\Huge}
\posttitle{\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}\hfill}
\predate{\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}\begin{flushright}\large}
\postdate{\end{flushright}\end{minipage}}

\title{Class Plan}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Less is More}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

There is one catch. I need this to work in my .emacs file. I would like the MACRO #+Title and #+Author to work **without extra code in my org-mode file**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is using boxes, in this case `\parbox`es (which allow for line breaks, as needed on the right) and putting them on the very left and right with `\hfill` in between.

Besides that, I wouldn't try to fix up `\maketitle` if I don't absolutely have to, but instead just create the title from scratch. To access the values of `\author` and `\title`, we can use the `titling` package.

The section titles can be done with a quick fix, too.

Here are a basic version and one that's closer to your image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
    \author{Author}
    \title{Class Plan}
    \date{\today}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{186,48,39}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Week \arabic{section}\hspace{1em}|}

\begin{document}

Basic version: \bigskip

\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont\thetitle}\hfill%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\raggedleft\today\\\theauthor%
}}

\bigskip Fancier version: \bigskip

\noindent\colorbox{titlebg}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\color{white}%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\thetitle}\hfill%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\raggedleft\thedate\\\theauthor%
}}}

\section{Less is More}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

Edit:

As egreg said, just redefine `\maketitle` as a whole and put this in a .sty file:

```
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{\noindent\colorbox{titlebg}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\color{white}%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\thetitle}\hfill%
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\raggedleft\today\\\theauthor%
}}}}
```

I'm not familiar with emacs at all, so I can't help you with that, if the package solution is not what you're looking for. In that case, I would probably recommend asking a separate question about what you're trying to do because it seems to be independent from the styling of the title (obeying our one-issue-per-question guideline).

Some resources on writing a package (= .sty file):

- [Make your own .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8750/4012) (good package template!)
- [Style/class tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528/4012)
- [How do I create a LaTeX package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34175/4012)

Comment: I did mark your answer as correct, but perhaps it was premature. It did indeed answer my question, however, I did not make my question clear enough. My ultimate goal is to include all of this in my .emacs file for a xelatex export. I was hoping to keep my solution above the \begin{document}, but your solution involves code below this point. Do you know how I could solve this? That is why I wanted to edit the \maketitle and I think in this case, I have to!

Comment: @macmadness86 The right place for that kind of code is *not* the `.emacs` file, but rather a personal `.sty` file. Just put the relevant code in a redefinition of `\maketitle`, inside `macmadness.sty` and do `\usepackage{macmadness}` after storing the package in one of the canonical places (`~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/macmadness` on Mac OS X with MacTeX).

Comment: @macmadness86: I agree with egreg, and see my edit.

Comment: @egreg I don't want to be one to argue with you, since you are like a tex genius answering every question on this site :) and you have helped me numerous times, but I would like to point out this site: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html which suggests putting these things in the .emacs file. Not sure if that is what you mean, but I have many templates in my .emacs which are selected with #+LaTeX_CLASS <name of class>. Anyway, I would like to make my solution as portable as possible between computers, which is why I don't really want a .sty file. I suppose I could do it

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for posting how to do with egreg suggested, because I did not know how to do that! I will try it out. I assume with a personal .sty file I can still use the article class? I would rather not have my own style in order to make my workflow more portable.

Comment: @macmadness86 .sty files are the epitome of LaTeX's portability! .emacs files presumably only work with emacs, .sty files work editor-independently! As a matter of fact, in the code you provided, you're loading fontenc.sty, titlesec.sty, blindtext.sty, color.sty & titling.sty -- and you can be sure that these packages load even more .sty files in the background. And yes, you can keep using `article`. A .sty file (= a package) is essentially nothing but normal LaTeX code put in an external file. [`\input{}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246) is similar, but usually used for document content.

Comment: @doncherry i meant between tex live installs. so that i can compile a file on any computer without needed to install a style file first. You make it sound fantastic though. You should go into sty file marketing :)

Comment: @macmadness86 "Installing" a style file is as easy as putting it in the directory of the mydocument.tex file that you're compiling. If you want to make it as available on a system as any other .sty file, you'll have to put it in your texmf tree, as egreg indicated.

Comment: @doncherry Thank you for that! I did not know you could just put it in the same directory as the tex file. I thought you had to put it in the texmf tree. I wanted to avoid that step, but I think I can live this solution! Both of you have been very helpful. Thanks guys!