# How to make .sty?

Tags: packages

I'm still new to how to make a package. How do you create the package in .sty format? Is the origin of .tex then changed to .sty?

Comment: A `.sty` is just input (almost) like any other file. Just make a file with that name and paste code there, and then `\usepackage{my_file_with_sty_extension}` in the document

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you agree that the answers to this question answer your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8750/138900

Comment: You can also use \input instead of \usepackage.  Note that MikTeX keeps an internal list of .sty files (fndb) and will only load .sty files from that list.